# biblatex-dw: Using back references in footnotes

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-dw

## Problem

Using the `biblatex` package with the `authortitle-dw` style I'd like point from a footnote back to its first occurence -- where it has been cited as a whole due to the `firstfull=true`-option -- as shown in the following picture:

[image]

<sup>(of course **not** in red and **not** with another font `:)` )</sup>

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle-dw,
    backend=biber,
    autocite=footnote,
    firstfull=true,
    singletitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {foo,
    author = {Foo, Francis},
    title = {All about Foo},
    year = {2011},
    location = {Footown},
}
@book {bar,
    author = {Bar, Bernie},
    title = {Barstory},
    year = {2000},
    location = {Barcity},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=150pt

\begin{document}

\autocite{bar}
\autocite{foo}
\autocite{bar}
\autocite{foo}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: You can use the style `footnote-dw`.

Comment: Explanation: The style `authortitle-dw` has no option to set a `seenote`. So you have to redefine the cite-command. It's easier to use `footnote-dw` ;-)

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Shame on me for not reading the manual! Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Thorsten, did you just not read the manual or was the manual too complicated to see that footnote-dw suits your needs better? I just ask, because I do not often get feedback on my manual and thus don’t know if it’s good or bad.

Comment: @domwass I just didn't read it. I like your style very much and also the manual is written very well. I just wasn't aware of the functionality of the `footnote-dw` style because I always used `authortitle-dw` and it was perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding on Marco Daniel's comment: `biblatex-dw` features two styles: `authortitle-dw` (based on the standard `authortitle` style) and `footnote-dw` (based on `authortitle-dw`, and similar to the standard `verbose-inote` style). The main differences between `authortitle` and `verbose` styles are:

- For `authortitle` styles, one is supposed to look up the full bibliographic information in the (mandatory) bibliography. By default, these styles do not display full information in an entry's first citation. (`authortitle-dw` offers the `firstfull` option, which is set to `false` by default.)
- `verbose` styles, on the other hand, do without a bibliography (though one is often added for convenience). The full bibliographic information is displayed in an entry's first (footnote) citation (which may introduce a shorthand for this entry), and follow-up citations will either use the shorthand or include a pointer to the first citation.

Bottom line: If you'd like to *"point from a footnote back to its first occurence"*, you are looking for a `verbose` style (here: `footnote-dw`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    style=footnote-dw,
    backend=biber,
    autocite=footnote,
    singletitle=true,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {foo,
    author = {Foo, Francis},
    title = {All about Foo},
    year = {2011},
    location = {Footown},
}
@book {bar,
    author = {Bar, Bernie},
    title = {Barstory},
    year = {2000},
    location = {Barcity},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=100pt

\begin{document}

\autocite{bar}
\autocite{foo}
\autocite{bar}
\autocite{foo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I could’nt have said it better.

Comment: @lockstep Thanks for your great explanation. It's quite obvious now that I didn't reflect much `:)`